# ¿Cómo asignarle a un Array devuelto por un servicio el tipo Array para que ngFor de Angular me lo admita?

Tags: html, mysql, nodejs, angular, typescript

Tengo un problema con Angular y Typescript con los Arrays y venía a ver si alguien me podía ayudar.

Tengo un backend con Node conectado con SQL cuyo método obtenerPasajeros hace un SELECT * FROM pasajeros (una tabla con columnas id y nombre) y lo devuelve al frontend:

```
obtenerPasajeros: function(req, res){

var queryString = "SELECT id FROM pasajeros";

con.query(queryString, function(err, pasajeros, fields){

  if(err) throw err;

  return res.status(200).send({pasajeros})

});}
```

Luego tengo un servicio en el frontend cuyo método obtener pasajeros hace la petición get al backend:

```
obtenerPasajeros(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.get(this.url+'obtener-pasajeros',{headers: headers});
}
```

Finalmente desde el .ts del componente creo un método que consume el servicio mediante el método obtenerPasajeros() anterior y se suscribe para recibir la respuesta (haciendo un console.log de lo que recibe):

[image: Método]

En el navegador el console.log devuelve un Array:

```
{pasajeros: Array(9)}
```

Al recibirlo, asigno el result a una variable pasajeros de tipo any:

```
  public pasajeros: any;
```

Y al tratar de recorrer esa variable en el ngFor, me salta el siguiente error:

```
      <select class="form-control" name="id" id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedPasajero">
    <option *ngFor="let p of pasajeros" [ngValue]="p">{{p}}</option>
  </select>

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

¿Cómo puede estar interpretando que no es un array? o formulado de otra forma, ¿cómo puedo asignarlo a una variable que pueda ser recorrida por el ngFor y pueda asignarle sus valores al select?

PD: Lo siento por los posibles errores pero es mi primera vez en el foro. Un saludo.

Comment: En la parte que dice `this.pasajeros = response` cambialo a `this.pasajeros = response.pasajeros` porque como esta ahora le asignabas el objetos reponse que no es admitido por el ciclo.

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Si pongo response.pasajeros me salta un error diciendo: "Property 'pasajeros' does not exist on type 'Object'" y no me lo acepta, ya lo probé anteriormente y no me funcionaba, por eso pregunté. :(

Comment: Intenta declarar pasajeros como array en vez de poner any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407618/angular-2-declaring-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Tal vez te sirva la referencia

Answer (score 0):

si le pones tipo any a la variable response del subscribe() typescript ya no se queja, porque por defecto si le pones tipo Object a una variable el compilador lo evalua siempre como un objeto vacio, da igual lo que lleve dentro.

En resumen, cambia el subscribe a esto:

```
this._pasajerosService.obtenerPasajeros().subscribe(
    (response:any)=>{
        this.pasajeros = response.pasajeros
    }
    (error:any)=>{
        console.log(error)
    }
)
```

Pruebalo y nos cuentas :)